# swift3 tableview refresh and Json issue

Tags: json, swift3, tableview, refresh

I have a tableview that must be create / refresh after the Json completely put into the Joblist array. Then the tableview can display the Joblist array properly. 
But if I refresh the tablebiew after the for loop, it shows 0 record. I have to refresh the tableview inside the for loop. It works properly, but it is not a good idea to do it, if the joblist array has a lot of record.
Please kindly help to solve this issue.

```
func parseJSON(json:Any){

        locationManager = CLLocationManager()

        if let okJSON = json as? [Any]{

            for item in okJSON {
                let infoDictionary = item as! [String:String]

                if let address = infoDictionary["City"] {
                    let geoCoder = CLGeocoder()
                    geoCoder.geocodeAddressString(address) { (placemarks, error) in
                        if error == nil && (placemarks?.count)! > 0 {

                            let location2 = placemarks?[0].location

                            if let location1 = self.locationManager?.location {
                                let distanceInMeters = location1.distance(from: location2!)
                                let IntDis = Int(distanceInMeters)
                                //print(IntDis)

                                if IntDis < 40000 {

                                    print(address)
                                    if let activityid       = infoDictionary["ActivityID"] {self.newJob.ActivityID=activityid}
                                    if let companyname      = infoDictionary["CompanyName"] {self.newJob.CompanyName=companyname}
                                    if let quantity         = infoDictionary["Quantity"] {self.newJob.Quantity=quantity}
                                    if let coupontitle      = infoDictionary["Title"] {self.newJob.CouponTitle=coupontitle}
                                    if let couponterms      = infoDictionary["Terms"] {self.newJob.CouponTerms=couponterms}
                                    if let expirdate        = infoDictionary["ExpirDate"] {self.newJob.ExpirDate=expirdate}
                                    if let contactperson    = infoDictionary["ContactPerson"] {self.newJob.ContactPerson=contactperson}
                                    if let tel              = infoDictionary["TEL"] {self.newJob.TEL=tel}

                                    self.joblist.append(self.newJob)
                                    print(self.joblist)
                                    //self.tableView.reloadData()
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: whenever you reload the table view then clear the array then load the data in this array so don't conflicts previous data.

Comment: reload tableview inside a for loop is working fine, but reload outside the for loop shows empty result in tableview. Is anyone can help?